# Is it possible to show this page in Addressbook with iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am trying to integrate the information in Addressbook into my iPhone application. Is there any way to push the view controller page into my current controller?

[alt text http://0.tqn.com/d/ipod/1/0/s/3/-/-/iphone_gallery_3.jpg](http://0.tqn.com/d/ipod/1/0/s/3/-/-/iphone_gallery_3.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an `ABPersonViewController`. You can give it an `ABRecordRef` (a person) from your address book and push it onto your navigation stack just as you would any other view controller.